# Java: Taking screenshots and making image with separate threads

Tags: java, screenshot, awtrobot

I am trying to take screenshot with Robot in 1 method and then with another method I am tring to write the BufferedImage produced by Robot without interrupting Robot from capturing screenshots. So far I came up with these:

**Screenshot Generation:**

```
public static void startRecord2() {
    Thread recordThread = new Thread() {
        //BufferedImage[] img;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //int vector_index =  -1 , 
            int phase_counter=0;
            Robot rt;
            BufferedImage[] img = null;
            try {
                rt = new Robot();
                record = true;
                int buffer_index = 0; 
                //boolean newCreatorStarted = false;
                long very_start = System.currentTimeMillis(), phase_start = 0, phase_end = 0;
                while (record) { //(cnt == 0 || record) {
                    if(buffer_index==0){
                        img = new BufferedImage[max_limit];
                        phase_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        phase_counter++;
                    }
                    //System.out.println("total_frame_created = "+total_frame_created);
                    img[ buffer_index++ ] = rt.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(screenWidth,screenHeight));
                    total_frame_created++;
                    //ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", new File("./"+store+"/"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg"));
                    if(buffer_index==max_limit||!record) {
                        buffer_index=0;
                        CreateImage(img, phase_counter);
                        img = null;
                        System.gc();
                        phase_end = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        System.out.println("Time taken in phase #"+phase_counter+" = "+ String.valueOf((phase_end-phase_start)/1000.0));
                    }
                }
                long very_end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("Time taken to capture "+total_frame_created+" shots = "+ (very_end-very_start)/1000 );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    recordThread.start();
}
```

**ImageWriting:**

```
public static void CreateImage(BufferedImage[] img, int phase){//, Thread capturerThread) {
    Thread imageCreatorThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            int index = 0;

            while(index<max_limit){
                try {
                    if(img[index]!=null) {
                        ImageIO.write(img[index++ ], "png", new File("./"+store+"/"+phase+"_"+index+".png"));
                        img[index-1]=null;
                    }else{
                        index-=1;
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Recorder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            System.gc();
            System.err.println("\t\t\tWritten "+index+" images to disk");
            total_image_created+=index;
        }
    };
    imageCreatorThread.start();
}
```

What I am doing here is- **When some frames (tried to denote it with max_limit with a value 30) the record method calls the ImageCreator method which starts another thread to process the BufferedImages it got through the parameter. Also, I want to keep the recorder method keep running to take screenshots continuously(or after some interval)**. But problem is,always after capturing 60 or aroung (sometimes found 61) frames, memory error occurs for Robot:

> Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>       at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.getRGBPixels(WRobotPeer.java:64)
>       at java.awt.Robot.createScreenCapture(Robot.java:444)
>       at Recorder$2.run(Recorder.java:124)
>               Written 60 images to disk

I tried changing heap memory with 512m, 1024m. Also I tried to make the BufferedImage array used in startRecord2 method null and call the Garbage Collector(Don't know if it can work). Nothing worked. What can I do to establish my algorithm?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your own code GC is not happening properly.

Before resolving the issue you must have to find out the culprit code which causing the memory leakage.
Increasing heap size will not resolve your issue as its sure that having issue memory leakage.
You can use any one the below tools to find out the memory leakage issue.

1) JAVA monitor
2) Jconsole
2) visualvm etc.